# How do I add a number into a sorted list?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, linked-list

So, I have an assignment from my school to add a number into a sorted list, but not just a list- IntNode list, which is if I get it right a linked list (maybe I'm wrong I dont know what this thing is called in English). Anyways, I'm very bad at it. So if someone could please look at my code and show me where my mistake is. I would appreciate that. right now, it returns -1, and I'm going insane! so here is the code:

```
public class IntNode
{
    private int value;
    private IntNode next;

    // constructors
    public IntNode(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public IntNode(int value, IntNode next)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    //getters

    public int GetValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }
    public IntNode GetNext()
    {
        return this.next;
    }
    // setters
    public void SetValue(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public void SetNext(IntNode next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
    public bool HasNext()
    {
        return this.next != null;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.value + "->";
    }
}

public static IntNode InsertIntoSortedList(IntNode list, int x)
    {
        IntNode p = list;
        int max = p.GetValue();
        Console.WriteLine("hila");
        if (p == null)
        {
            p.SetValue(x);
            return p;
        }
            
        while(p!=null&& x!=0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hola");
            if (x<p.GetNext().GetValue()){
                p=p.GetNext();

            }
            else
            {
                p.GetNext().SetValue(x);
                x = 0;
                p= p.GetNext();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("halo");
        Console.WriteLine(list.ToString());
        return list;

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntNode list = new IntNode(1, new IntNode(4, new IntNode(9, new IntNode(12, new IntNode(72)))));
        Console.WriteLine(InsertIntoSortedList(list, 7));

    }
}
```

Comment: This line `Console.WriteLine(list.ToString());` is producing unexpected output (like `1->`), please debug it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as @Luuk mentioned, it would be very useful if you had `toString` method for node so that you can easily see if your operation succeeded or not. It can look something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    String ret = "";
    IntNode current = this;

    while (current != null)
    {
        ret += current.GetValue();
        if (current.GetNext() != null)
        {
            ret += " -> ";
        }
        current = current.GetNext();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

After that we can reimplement your function for adding new node:

```
public static IntNode InsertIntoSortedList(IntNode list, int x)
{
    IntNode newNode = new IntNode(x);
    // in case that new node is before everyone else or if list is empty
    if (list == null || x <= list.GetValue())
    {
        newNode.SetNext(list);
        return newNode;
    }

    IntNode current = list;
    // we iterate through the list until we find the node after which the new node should be inserted
    while (current.GetNext() != null && x > current.GetNext().GetValue())
    {
        current = current.GetNext();
    }

    newNode.SetNext(current.GetNext());
    current.SetNext(newNode);

    return list;
}
```

You can test it out now:

```
IntNode list = new IntNode(1, new IntNode(4, new IntNode(9, new IntNode(12, new IntNode(72)))));
IntNode l = InsertIntoSortedList(list, 7);
Console.WriteLine(l);
l = InsertIntoSortedList(l, -2);
Console.WriteLine(l);
l = InsertIntoSortedList(l, 78);
Console.WriteLine(l);
l = InsertIntoSortedList(l, 50);
Console.WriteLine(l);
```

Output is:

```
1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 9 -> 12 -> 72
-2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 9 -> 12 -> 72
-2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 9 -> 12 -> 72 -> 78
-2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 9 -> 12 -> 50 -> 72 -> 78
```

Answer (score 1):

first, the ToString method will not work, it will only print the nodes value and will not print the rest of the list
the ToString method should look like this:

```
public override string ToString() {
    if (this.next == null)
        return this.value + "-->null";
    return this.value + "-->" + this.next;
}
```

next, at the start of the function you perform a check to check if p is null (which means it's an invalid object) therefor you cannot set its value to x

```
if (p == null) {
    return new IntNode(x);
}
```

in your soultion you didnt consider the case where x < p.value this can be checked using:

```
if (x < p.GetValue()) {
    return new IntNode(x, p);
}
```

and last, in your while loop you check if the pointer isnt null and if x isnt 0, but what about the case where x is 0, also you perform an action on p.next where it might not be a valid object. in addtion to that you change the value of p.next insted ot adding a new element.
your while loop can be changed to this:

```
while (p.HasNext() && p.GetNext().GetValue() < x) {
    p = p.GetNext();
}
    
p.SetNext(new IntNode(x, p.GetNext()));
```

so your final function should look like this:

```
public static IntNode InsertIntoSortedList(IntNode list, int x) {
    IntNode p = list;
    if (p == null){
        return new IntNode(x);
    }

    if (x < p.GetValue()) {
        return new IntNode(x, p);
    }

    while (p.HasNext() && p.GetNext().GetValue() < x) {
        p = p.GetNext();
    }
    
    p.SetNext(new IntNode(x, p.GetNext()));
    return list;
}
```